# 8 Queen Problem - Lua, why does this output only 5 queens?

Tags: algorithm, lua, n-queens

Exercise 2.2: An alternative implementation for the eight-queen problem would be to generate all possible permutations of 1 to 8 and, for each permutation, to check whether it is valid. Change the program to use this approach. How does the performance of the new program compare with the old one? (Hint: compare the total number of permutations with the number of times that the original program calls the function isplaceok.)

My code:

```
    function isPlaceSafe(board, queen, column) 
    for z = 1, queen - 1 do -- i 1, queen - 1 dltg, ze w lua zaczynamy od jedynki
        if (board[z] == column) or  -- same column
            -- queen = queen row (Y)
            -- column = queen column (X)
            -- column - board[z] == queen - z
            (queen - z == column - board[z]) or 
            (queen - z == board[z] - column) then
            return false 
        end 
    end
    return true 
end 


function printSolutions(board) 
    for i = 1, N do
        for j = 1, N do
            io.write(board[i] == j and "X"  or "-", " ")
        end 
        io.write("\n")
    end
    io.write("\n")
end 

--[[
function addQueen(board, number) 
    if number > N then
        printSolutions(board)
        os.exit() 
    else
        for c = 1, N do
            if (isPlaceSafe(board, number, c)) then
                board[number] = c
                addQueen(board, number + 1)
            end
        end
    end
end 

addQueen({}, 1)

--]]
board = {}
function generatePermutations()
    for a = 1, N do -- row
        for b = 1, N do -- column
            if isPlaceSafe(board, a, b) then
                board[a] = b
            end
 
            print(a .. " " .. b)
        end
    end
    printSolutions(board)
end

generatePermutations()
```

Output :

```
- - - - - - - X 
- - - - - X - - 
- - - X - - - - 
- - - - - - X - 
- - - - X - - - 
- - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
```

why does this code stop at only 5 queens?

Comment: It stops at 5 queens because there are no more places where a queen can be placed without being attacked. Your code only places each queen at the first possible location, without checking any of the other possibilities.

Comment: how to check other possibilities then? I don't get it.

Comment: consider placing queen as step. You place 1st queen on first line (8 options), 2-nd queen os 2nd line etc. If you cant make n-th placement change your (n-1)-th placement, if you exhausted all possible (n-1)-th placements then change (n-2)-th placement and so on.